# Even after i have uninstalled Rhythmbox and Transmission, Software center keeps showing updates for them?

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-center

As mentioned, i removed a lot of the stuff that i didnt need from the default install, and mostly there hasnt been any problem. However, Software center keeps showing updates for rhythmbox and transmission enough though these were probably the first things i uninstalled.
How do i stop Software Center from showing updates for them ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that these packages are "related packages" (for lack of better term) to Rhythmbox, et. al.; libraries and dependencies that your uninstall overlooked (as often happens).

I suggest you use the "Computer Janitor" utility to clean-up everything no longer needed. It's safer to do a clean-up after uninstalling this way rather than removing the packages manually. Sometimes, it may happen that the package's labeling makes it sound like only a certain program (Rhythmbox, Transmission, take your pick) relies on it when in truth there are others that need it.

If you want to do it via terminal, the command `sudo apt-get autoremove` seems to do exactly what Janitor does.

Comment: Cant this be done without the janitor ?

Comment: Well, you can always deal directly with the package manager. But I really find janitor to be a more user-friendly approach. Why? Having issues with janitor?

Comment: No. Its just that i prefer code

Comment: Hi. I've edited my answer for a terminal trick I just discovered. Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: It did nothing !! :P
0 removed , 0 changed